# Spring Security not using custom UserDetaisService

Tags: java, security, spring-security

I am using Spring Security 4.2.5 and I am trying to set up a simple Login page using 'username' and 'password' to have a user login.  Right now, I am not worried about whether it comes in via http, or https.  I will change that setting later on.  What I am trying to do is to get Spring Security to see the username/password, call my UserDetailsService class, authenticate the request, and then redirect the browser to 'index.html'.  The problem I am having is I keep getting access denied.  I turned on debug logging and noticed that my custom UserDetalsService is not being called to get the User data.  What is missing to get Spring Security to call AdminUserService?  I can provide logging statements if need be.

```
<body>

    <div>
        <div>
            <h2>Login</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <form action="/admin/login" method="post">
        Login:<br>
        <input type="text" name="username">
        <br>
        Password:<br>
        <input type="text" name="password">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

</body>
```

My applicationContext.xml file looks like

```
<beans
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.2.xsd">

<import resource="classpath:my-admin-context.xml" />

<bean id="adminUserService" class="....AdminUserService">
    <property name="userMapper" ref="userMapper" />
    <property name="userRoleMapper" ref="userRoleMapper" />
</bean>

<bean id="adminAuthenticationSuccessHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/index.html" />
    <property name="alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl" value="true" />
    <property name="useReferer" value="true" />
</bean>

<security:http>

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login.html*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" requires-channel="any" />

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" requires-channel="any" />

    <security:form-login login-page="/login.html" authentication-success-handler-ref="adminAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
    <security:logout logout-url="/logout" invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" logout-success-url="/login.html" />

</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="adminUserService">
        <security:password-encoder hash="sha" />
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

The AdminUserSerivce looks like

```
public class AdminUserService implements UserDetailsService {

private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

private UserMapper userMapper;

private UserRoleMapper userRoleMapper;

public UserMapper getUserMapper() {

    return userMapper;
}

@Required
public void setUserMapper(final UserMapper userMapper) {

    this.userMapper = userMapper;
}

public UserRoleMapper getUserRoleMapper() {

    return userRoleMapper;
}

@Required
public void setUserRoleMapper(final UserRoleMapper userRoleMapper) {

    this.userRoleMapper = userRoleMapper;
}

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    logger.debug("Looking up User: {}", username);

    final UserDo userDo = userMapper.findUserByLogin(username);
    User user = null;

    if (userDo == null) {
        logger.warn("User does not exist: {}", username);

        user = new User(username, null, false, false, false, false, new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>());
    } else if (StringUtils.equals(userDo.getStatus(), EtpAdminConstants.INACTIVE)) {
        logger.warn("User is Inactive: {}", username);
        logger.info("User DO: {}", userDo);

        user = new User(username, null, false, false, false, false, new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>());
    } else {
        final List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = getAuthorities(userDo);

        logger.debug("Granted Authorities: {}", authorities);

        user = new User(username, userDo.getPassword(), authorities);
    }

    return user;
}

List<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(final UserDo userDo) {

    final List<UserRole> userRoleList = userRoleMapper.findRoleMapping(userDo.getId());

    logger.debug("Found Roles: {}", userRoleList);

    final List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();

    userRoleList.forEach(userRole -> authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userRole.getRoleName())));

    return authorities;
}
```

}

Here is the Logging information

```
[o.a.c.a.AuthenticatorBase] Security checking request POST /admin/login
[o.a.c.a.AuthenticatorBase] Not subject to any constraint
[o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher] Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/login.htm*'
[o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy] /login at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ChannelProcessingFilter'
[o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher] Request '/login' matched by universal pattern '/**'
[o.s.s.w.a.c.ChannelProcessingFilter] Request: FilterInvocation: URL: /login; ConfigAttributes: [ANY_CHANNEL]
[o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy] /login at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
[o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
[o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@7a1cf085. A new one will be created.
[o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy] /login at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
[o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy] /login at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
[o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy] /login at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
[o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy] /login at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
[o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest] pathInfo: both null (property equals)
[o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest] queryString: both null (property equals)
[o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest] requestURI: arg1=/admin/login; arg2=/admin/login (property equals)
[o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest] serverPort: arg1=8080; arg2=8080 (property equals)
[o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest] requestURL: arg1=http://localhost:8080/admin/login; arg2=http://localhost:8080/admin/login (property equals)
[o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest] scheme: arg1=http; arg2=http (property equals)
[o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest] serverName: arg1=localhost; arg2=localhost (property equals)
[o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest] contextPath: arg1=/admin; arg2=/admin (property equals)
[o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest] servletPath: arg1=/login; arg2=/login (property equals)
[o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache] [http-nio-8080-exec-5]: Removing DefaultSavedRequest from session if present
[o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy] /login at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
[o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy] /login at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
[o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter] Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@90576bf4: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@21a2c: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: FBB14A73FFEA49FF371DE7E74DBCBF31; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
[o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy] /login at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
[o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy] /login at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
[o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy] /login at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
[o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor] Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /login; Attributes: [ROLE_ADMIN]
[o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor] Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@90576bf4: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@21a2c: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: FBB14A73FFEA49FF371DE7E74DBCBF31; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
[o.s.s.a.v.AffirmativeBased] Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter@5b444231, returned: -1
[o.s.s.a.v.AffirmativeBased] Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter@52a53135, returned: 0
[o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'sqlSessionFactory'
[o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter] Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
[o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache] DefaultSavedRequest added to Session: DefaultSavedRequest[http://localhost:8080/admin/login]
[o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter] Calling Authentication entry point.
[o.s.s.w.DefaultRedirectStrategy] Redirecting to 'http://localhost:8080/admin/login.html'
[o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
[o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter] SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out.  @vikas, that little bit of information got me in the right direction.  Thanks!  I had the wrong configuration. At the bottom of this answer is the configuration I had to go with.  You will notice a couple of things:

1. Create a separate `<http>` for the login.html page.
2. You must specify the following parameters on the `<form-login>`

   - login-processing-url
   - username-parameter
   - password-parameter

Spring Security will not find '/login'. You must specify this parameter, contrary to what the documentation says.

*"The login form simply contains **username** and **password** input fields, and posts to the URL that is monitored by the filter (by default this is /login)."* -- [Form Login Filter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#form-login-filter)

Also, Spring Security will not find the default 'username' and 'password, contrary to the documentation.

*"Login forms must present two parameters to this filter: a username and password. The default parameter names to use are contained in the static fields SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_USERNAME_KEY and SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_PASSWORD_KEY. The parameter names can also be changed by setting the usernameParameter and passwordParameter properties."* -- [UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.html)

Code snippet is from the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter class.

```
public static final String SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_USERNAME_KEY = "username";
public static final String SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_PASSWORD_KEY = "password";
```

You must specify these 3 parameters in your configuration.

```
<security:http pattern="/login.htm*" security="none" />

    <security:http>

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" requires-channel="any" />

        <security:form-login login-page="/login.html" login-processing-url="/login" authentication-success-handler-ref="adminAuthenticationSuccessHandler" username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password"/>

        <security:logout logout-url="/logout" invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" logout-success-url="/login.html" />

    </security:http>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are securing all request using below line

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" requires-channel="any" />
```

So Please permit all user to access login request.
    **"/Login.html*"** is not pattern.

Comment: So, I am clear.  I should remove the intercept-url for "Login.html*" and add the following line above the main <http> with <security:http pattern="/login.htm*" security="none" />?  If so, that didn't work.  I also tried to changing the pattern and the access to ROLE_ANONYMOUS in the intercept-url and that didn't work.  The login.html page comes up just fine.  The problem is when I click on the **Submit** button, Spring Security does not call the UesrDetailsService.